# time-series prediction for price forecasting (problems with predictions)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I am working on a project for price movement forecasting and I am stuck with poor quality predictions.

At every time-step I am using an LSTM to predict the next 10 time-steps. The input is the sequence of the last 45-60 observations. I tested several different ideas, but they all seems to give similar results. The model is trained to minimize MSE.

For each idea I tried a model predicting 1 step at a time where each prediction is fed back as an input for the next prediction, and a model directly predicting the next 10 steps(multiple outputs). For each idea I also tried using as input just the moving average of the previous prices, and extending the input to input the order book at those time-steps.
Each time-step corresponds to a second.

These are the results so far:

1- The first attempt was using as input the moving average of the last N steps, and predict the moving average of the next 10. 
At time t, I use the ground truth value of the price and use the model to predict t+1....t+10

This is the result

[Predicting moving average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOXxu.png)

On closer inspection we can see what's going wrong:

[Prediction seems to be a flat line. Does not care much about the input data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Xb5.png)

2) The second attempt was trying to predict differences, instead of simply the price movement. The input this time instead of simply being X[t] (where X is my input matrix) would be X[t]-X[t-1].
This did not really help.
The plot this time looks like this:

[Predicting differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toFGz.png)

But on close inspection, when plotting the differences, the predictions are always basically 0.

[Plot of differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSqGU.png)

At this point, I am stuck here and running our of ideas to try. I was hoping someone with more experience in this type of data could point me in the right direction.

Am I using the right objective to train the model? Are there any details when dealing with this type of data that I am missing?
Are there any "tricks" to prevent your model from always predicting similar values to what it last saw? (They do incur in low error, but they become meaningless at that point).

At least just a hint on where to dig for further info would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Am I using the right objective to train the model?

Yes, but LSTM are always very tricky for forecasting time series. And are very prone to overfitting compared to other time series models.

> Are there any details when dealing with this type of data that I am missing?
>
> Are there any "tricks" to prevent your model from always predicting similar values to what it last saw?

I haven't seen your code, or the details of the LSTM you are using. Make sure you are using a very small network, and you are avoiding overfitting. Make sure that after you differenced the data - you then reintegrate it before evaluating the final forecast.

On trick to try to build a model that forecasts 10 steps ahead directly instead of building a one-step ahead model and then forecasting recursively.